# How to access the global window variable if there's a local window variable?

Tags: javascript, global-variables, local-variables

Just out of curiosity, how would you access the global window object inside a function with this signature:

```
function bla(window){
   // How to access the global 'window' object here? Because 'window' is now local.
}
```

Comment: Can this help?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33458255/passing-a-window-object-into-javascript-namespace

Comment: Why shadow `window` like that? Also window is a reserved word in javascript and should never be used as a local

Comment: @charlietfl — It is not [a reserved word](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#reserved_keywords_as_of_ecmascript_2015) although shadowing it is a bad idea. This feels very much like a "Doctor! It hurts when I do this!" "So don't do that" problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [`globalThis`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/globalThis)

```js
a = 1;

function x(window) {
  console.log(window.a)
  console.log(globalThis.a)
}

x({ a: 2 })
```